# Grabbing HTML source, how can I grab the HTML in the state it would be in after the page loads?

Tags: java, html, minecraft

I have been working on grabbing html source for a client I made, so I decided that I would like to get the status of the minecraft login and session servers. There is already a website that does this, so I figured I could just grab the HTML and search through it with Java. After a test run, I noticed the output was not what I am looking for.

[image]

I'm hoping to be able to achieve an output of something more like on this site.
[MC Status](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/)

```
public class Status {
    private static Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();

    public static void toggle(String s) {
        if (s.contentEquals("-status")) {
            Variables.status = !Variables.status;

            if (Variables.status) {
                enable();
            } else {
                disable();
            }
        } else {
            update();
        }
    }

    public static void enable() {
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatTeal + "Minecraft Status enabled.");
    }

    public static void disable() {
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatTeal + "Minecraft Status disabled.");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void update() {
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;
        String s;
        int i = 1;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/");
            HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
            httpcon.connect();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) httpcon.getContent()));

            Variables.statusList.clear();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i == 65 || i == 72 || i == 79 || i == 86 || i == 93) {
                    s = line.replaceAll("<div class=\"name\">", "").trim();
                    line = s.replaceAll("</div>", "").trim();
                    Variables.statusNameList.add(line);

                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                if (i == 66 || i == 73 || i == 80 || i == 87 || i == 94) {
                    s = line.replaceAll("<h2 class=\"status\">", "").trim();
                    line = s.replaceAll("â€¦</h2>", "").trim();

                    Variables.statusList.add(line);

                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                i++;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a much easier way to test this than to scrape the official status page - for each server you want to test, just try connecting to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to greatly simplify this and ended up settling for a simple text output. Seems to work fine for my needs.

```
public class Status {
    private static Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();

    public static void getStatus() {
        String status = IOHandler.getHtmlSource("http://status.mojang.com/check");
        String[] statusArray = status.split(",");
        String a = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < statusArray.length; i++) {
            a = statusArray[i].replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\"", " ")
                    .replaceAll("\\:", "-").replaceAll("\\}", "")
                    .trim();

            if (a.contains("green")) {
                a = a.replaceAll(" - green", "");
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatBGreen + a);
            } else if (a.contains("yellow")) {
                a = a.replaceAll(" - yellow", "");
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatYellow + a);
            } else if (a.contains("red")) {
                a = a.replaceAll(" - red", "");
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatDRed + a);
            } else {
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(Variables.ChatDRed + "ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page is using JavaScript to load the statuses of Mojang's services. Additionally, the page is behind cloudflare which can occasionally do browser checks. You would need to use a Java browser emulator, such as HtmlUnit. Why don't you just ping Mojang's servers yourself and see if they're online or not? Surely that's much easier than parsing this page.